# Write an expression in javascript

Tags: javascript

I need a javascript code that split a string like below:

Input string: "a=>aa| b=>b||b | c=>cc"

Output:

```
a=>aa

b=>b||b 

c=>cc
```

I'd written different codes like:

```
split(/ \ | /)
```

or

```
split(/ \| (?! \ |) /)
```

but didn't work.

please help me...

I really need it fast.

Answer (score 3):

Split with `/\|(?=\s)/` for your case

```
"a=>aa| b=>b||b | c=>cc".split(/\|(?=\s)/)
# a=>aa
# b=>b||b 
# c=>cc
```

Comment: Note: my answer only works for OP's example. please take a look Kobi's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719300/write-an-expression-in-javascript/2719388#2719388), thats more appropriate one actually.

Answer (score 1):

This confusing looking regex will work without spaces around the pipes:

```
var matches = "a=>aa|b=>b||b|c=>cc".match(/(?:[^|]|\|\|)+/g)
```

Instead of splitting, it searches for tokens with double pipes, but not single. If you have spaces and need to match `b=>b|b | c=>5` use S.Mark's regex, but this can help in other cases.
To clarify, `[^|]|\|\|` reads `[not a pipe] OR [two pipes]`.

Comment: Thanks. That depends on the context though, if the OP has tokens with single pipes (which is very possible), your version will work better.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the first answer and it did not work as I believe you intended:

```
"a=>aa| b=>b||b | c=>cc".split( "\| ");
```

unfortunately the answer that I came up with isn't much better just add a space after the pipe marker in your regex. Also answer by @S.Mark is valid, tested.