# Help for splitting a string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

[I'd asked a question about the splitting the a string like below:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719300/write-an-expression-in-javascript)

Input string: `a=>aa| b=>b||b | c=>cc`

and the output:

```
a=>aa
b=>b||b 
c=>cc
```

Kobi's answer was:

```
var matches = "a=>aa|b=>b||b|c=>cc".match(/(?:[^|]|\|\|)+/g)
```

His answer worked, but I need to use the `.split()` method and store the outputs in an array.

So I can't use the `.match()` Method.

How can I do it?

Comment: One question about the "output" - do you want `['a=>aa', 'b=>b||b', 'c=>cc']`, or are you coming from a PHP background and thinking about a "hash table" (just an object in JS) `{"a": "aa", "b": "b||b", "c":"cc"}`?

Answer (score 2):

Here's my stab:

```
var str = 'a=>aa| b=>b||b | c=>cc';
var arr = str.split(/\s*\|\s+/);
console.log(arr)
// ["a=>aa", "b=>b||b", "c=>cc"]

var obj = {}; // if we want the "object format"
for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
  str=arr[i];
  var match = str.match(/^(\w+)=>(.*)$/);

  if (match) { obj[match[1]] = match[2]; }
}
console.log(obj);

// Object { a:"aa", b:"b||b", c: "cc" }
```

And the RegExp:

```
/
 \s*   # Match Zero or more whitespace
 \|    # Match '|'
 \s+   # Match one or more whitespace (to avoid the ||)
/
```

Answer (score 1):

.match return array too, so there is no problem using .match

```
arr = "a=>aa|b=>b||b|c=>cc".match(/(?:[^|]|\|\|)+/g)
// a=>aa,b=>b||b,c=>cc
arr.length
// 3
arr[0]
// a=>aa
```

Comment: actually I need this question for my complier course.
I explained the match function to my professor and he said that you must answer this question with split...
One more thing: 
the input is : a=>aa|b=>b||b|c=>cc (there is no space between each character)

Answer (score 1):

While I hate arguing with myself, another possible solution is:

```
var matches = 'a=>aa|b=>b||b|c=>cc'.split(/\b\s*\|\s*\b/g);
```

Meaning: split when you see `|` surrounded by spaces, and between alphanumeric characters.
 This version will also leaves `d|=d` intact.
`\b` can introduce errors though, it might will not split if the pipe isn't between alphanumeric characters, for example `a=>(a+a)|b=>b` will not split.

Answer (score 0):

I posted this in your other copy of this question (please don't ask a question multiple times!)

This ought to do it:

```
"a=>aa|b=>b||b|c=>cc".split(/\|(?=\w=>)/);
```

which yields:

```
["a=>aa", "b=>b||b", "c=>cc"]
```